# How to get Zero Returned Instead of NaN Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a DataFrame that looks like:

```
    date    city    debit
0   2019    NY  89.40
1   2020    NY  4.33
2   2021    NY  12.00
3   2020    LA  0.00
4   2021    LA  5.40
```

code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: 2019, 1: 2020, 2: 2021, 3: 2020, 4: 2021},
                   'city': {0: 'NY', 1: 'NY', 2: 'NY', 3: 'LA', 4: 'LA'},
                   'debit': {0: 89.4, 1: 4.33, 2: 12.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 5.4}})
```

If I want average debit of the past years per city per year that has an "N" in the name I would simply do:

```
df[df['city'].str.contains('N')].groupby('date').sum()['debit'].mean()
```

and it would return `35.243333` which is perfect.

If I want to see the average debit of the past years per city that has "ZZ" in the name (for this case there is **none**), how do I get the result to be **zero**.

When I use `df[df['city'].str.contains('ZZ')].groupby('date').sum()['debit'].mean()` I get `NaN` which causes error in my code down the line. I also want to avoid using if statements if possible.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: use df.fillna(0). You can do df[df['city'].str.contains('ZZ')].groupby('date').mean()['debit'].fillna(0)

Comment: That does not work as the problem is even if the column has NA the groupby returns an empty DataFrame which is why the `NaN` occurs on the `.mean()`

Answer (score 0):

This provides you the correct output in both scenarios. The idea here is as you said you will get a blank dataframe, so you have to make a new dataframe df2, and fill it with your results.

```
df2=df[['date']].drop_duplicates()
df2['debit']=0
df2=df2.set_index('date')
s=df[df['city'].str.contains('ZZ')].groupby('date').mean()['debit']
df2.loc[s.index.to_list(),'debit']=s
df2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AHhhhhhh the answer was so simple. Just add `np.nan_to_num` in front of the code and it turns `nan`'s to zeros but also keeps the original number if there is one